# How flexible is meteor-roles package?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am building a website in which there will be no registration. The super admin will be responsible to add users as admins, employee, or normal user.

the super admin will have a form to fill in from username, email, password, and user level (admin, employee, or normal user.) and then submit button to store the user to the database.

Admin, employee, and the normal user, each will have different roles.

My question is, it is possible to store the user in the database and assign it to its related roles based on the super admin choice (admin, employee, or normal user)?

Comment: Are you talking about this package: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles?

Comment: @Khang yes, thats the package I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's flexible enough for what you want.

When the form is submitted, you will need to call `Accounts.createUser`, followed by `Roles.addUsersToRoles`

[See Docs here](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles#roles-usage)

Also, consider immediately triggering a [Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail](http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-resetPassword) call to send an email with a link the user can use to set their initial password (not known by super-admin, or a default password).

Comment: thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted to hear so that I don't get into trouble in later stages in development, :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with alanning:roles you could do that using either `Roles.setUserRoles` or `Roles.addUsersToRoles` like this:

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(Meteor.userId(), ['admin']);
```

The code abode adds the logged-in user to admin role. Then you could check if a user has role by:

```
Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'admin');
```